# Replace back slash (\) with forward slash (/)

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to replace this path: `C:\test1\test2`
into this:
`C:/test1/test2`

I am using jquery but it doesn't seem to work

```
var path = "C:\test1\test2";
var path2 = path.replace("\", "//");
```

How should it be done?

Comment: Just FYI this has nothing to do with jQuery - it's pure JS. I retagged the question for you

Answer (score 64, accepted):

You have to escape to backslashes.

```js
var path = "C:\\test1\\test2";
var path2 = path.replace(/\\/g, "/");
console.log(path2);
```

Comment: how can we do for '\' single backslash to forward '/'?

Comment: @Code_S: My answer is working for a single backslash. But, because you have to escape the backslash with another backslah, you have 2 backslashes in the regex.

Comment: var path = "C:\test1\test2";
var path2 = path.replace(/\\/g, "/");
console.log(path2);

It is not working and I have tried , could you let us know how could it be done. Thanks

Comment: @Code_S: You also have to escape the backslash in the string `var path = "C:\\test1\\test2";` As you can see, it works when you run the code snippet.

Comment: It works in the snippet because there are two backslashes and not only one like asked in the question

Comment: @PierBJX: There are double backslashes in the string because backslash have to be escaped. If you print the string, you will get `C:\test1\test2`. Test it.

Comment: Yes, I agree but it does not answer the question at the end. Why it does not work if you do directly `'C:\test1\test2'.replace(/\\/g, "/")` ?

Comment: @PierBJX: Have you printed `path` when `var path = "C:\\test1\\test2";` and `var path = 'C:\test1\test2';`? The former gives `C:\test1\test2`, the later `C:    est1    est2` where `\t` is replaced by a tabulation. Or you have to use `String.raw`. In the code snippet it is just a way to assign the value.

Comment: Yes yes I printed and I totally agree with you. It is just if you do it inline `'C:\test1\test2'.replace(/\\/g, "/")` like this it does not work. You have to use `String.raw` as you mentionned => String.raw ` C:\test1\test2 ` .replace(/\\/g, "/")

Comment: Just in-case someone ever gets this far and is still stuck. A single backslash can't be replaced, because it is automatically escaped before the replace can happen. However you can disable escaping like this:  ```(String.raw`C:\test1\test2`).replace(/\\/g, "/")```

Answer (score 3):

Your original string is in the wrong format, as '\t' inside it is for a tab symbol. Please change it (may be from the server side) to this:

```
    var path = "C:\\test1\\test2";
```

so your code could change to this:

```
    var path = "C:\\test1\\test2";
    var path2 = path.replace(/\\/g, '/');
```

Comment: This does not work with only one backslash like asked in the question