# replacing JS backslashes in unicode text

Tags: javascript, replace, backslash

I'm having a tough time trying to replace some `\_` in some text in JS.
I've tried various combinations with `fromCharCode` and `split` but cannot seem to find success.

In all these cases the output is identical to the input, I can't rip out or replace the junk characters. It seems the backslash-underscore is invisible to JS. Wondering if it's related to the string being unicode?

Suggestions appreciated!

```js
let v1 = {
  s: "生病以后，爸爸\_什么\_酒\_都\_不\_能喝了"
}

let v2 = { ...v1 }  // copy
let v3 = { ...v2 }  // copy

v2.s = v2.s.replace(/\\/g, "X")
v3.s = v3.s.split(String.fromCharCode(92)).join("Y")

console.log("v1", v1)
console.log("v2", v2)
console.log("v3", v3)
```

At this point I might mess with a sed script ;.;

related checked do not solve:
[Javascript and backslashes replace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2479309/javascript-and-backslashes-replace)
[Replace back slash (\) with forward slash (/)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42855606/replace-back-slash-with-forward-slash)
[Converting backslashes into forward slashes using javascript does not work properly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6417641/converting-backslashes-into-forward-slashes-using-javascript-does-not-work-prope)

Comment: What is your desired result?

Answer (score 1):

When you are assigning your string like this:

```
let v1 = {
  s: "生病以后，爸爸\_什么\_酒\_都\_不\_能喝了"
}
```

All backslashes will be removed and your result string will be `生病以后，爸爸_什么_酒_都_不_能喝了`

So you have to escape those backslashes as well:

```
let v1 = {
  s: "生病以后，爸爸\\_什么\\_酒\\_都\\_不\\_能喝了"
}
```

And now to achieve your expected result you can use next replace regexp:

```
v1.s = v1.s.replace(/\\_/g, 'X');
```

Comment: OK thats a good point. I do have source content which has those glitches in, I can see in the txt files.I was trying to reproduce that data in a simple test case... but creating the test content I screwed up doh!

Comment: any thoughts how I could create a string with the bogus characters in from raw JS?

Comment: @dcsan try to escape backslashes `"生病以后，爸爸\\_什么\\_酒\_都\\_不\\_能喝了"` )